# Python Query - Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Create two arrays using `numpy`. One called students with as values.

```
['Janet', 'Adriana', 'Manual', 'Mohamed', 'Leann']
```

Another is called grades as values:

```
[[93, 85], [78, 80], [94, 93], [75, 90], [92, 87]]
```

Select all rows from grades where student is either `'Adriana' or 'Mohamed'`

How do i go about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

```
import numpy as np
students = ['Janet', 'Adriana', 'Manual', 'Mohamed', 'Leann']
grades = [[93, 85], [78, 80], [94, 93], [75, 90], [92, 87]]
arr_s = np.asarray(students)
arr_g = np.asarray(grades)
mask = np.isin(arr_s, ['Adriana', 'Mohamed'])
res = arr_g[mask]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
array([[78, 80],
       [75, 90]])
```

Comment: Hi in this solution, you are not creating arrays as mentioned in the question. How can i solve this after creating arrays?

Comment: @IAwa, Are you want this : `print([g for s, g in zip(students, grades) if s in ['Adriana', 'Mohamed']])`

Comment: All im saying is that we need to create arrays of students and grades first by using numpy first as per the question requirement.

Comment: @IAwa, where do you mention `numpy`? edit the question and ask exactly.